# UITableView strategy for empty sections and adding rows inline with custom cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm working on an app and I'm running into some problems on how to work out this functionality.  I've pieced a crude wireframe together:

[image: wireframe]

Essentially, if no data exists in the section, I have a custom 'Empty data' cell display. In the `numberOfRowsInSection` delegate call, I had a simple test where if my array count is 0, return 1. I assume its hacky so if there is a better approach please let me know.

My problem is I also have a custom 'Input' cell that I want to appear inline in the section, replacing the 'Empty' cell. I was able to piece that together by adding a string to my data array, then calling the `tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths` with some very crazy conditionals in my `tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

What I can't get working is if a user cancels, rather than saving, I want the 'Input' cell to disappear and the 'Empty' cell to return. I can't just remove my custom string from my data array because tableView throws an error that my datasource count wasn't expected because I used the removeRowsAtIndexPaths to remove one row.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have more than one section?

Comment: Can you post the code please?

Answer (score 0):

the better approch would be dynamically hide the tableview and add a placeholderview -- I wouldnt 'misuse' the table view for that

the 'input view' and 'the empty cell' would be independent of a table

Comment: I think the problem with is that either section can be empty. So I'd need the empty cell view to scroll along with tableView, and calculate spacing in the tableView. It felt like my 'EmptyCell'/'InputCell' approach would be easier to implement than hooking a separate view into all of the resizing/scrolling logic to ensure it stays in proper position. If you have any info or something I haven't considered, please share I'd definitely like to learn more about the lifecycle.